# Prepared statement in Hibernate doesn't work

Tags: hibernate

When I do the following query:

```
return (Formation) em
    .createQuery(
            "SELECT f FROM Formation f WHERE f.model" + modelType + "= :modelId")
    .setParameter("modelId", modelId)
    .getSingleResult();
```

I get this error :

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of model.configuration.Model.id

When I replace the prepared statement by an ugly query like the one above, it works:

```
return (Formation) em
    .createQuery(
            "SELECT f FROM Formation f WHERE f.model" + modelType + "= " + modelId)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Do you have a getter and setter for the modelId attribute in the Formation class?

Comment: I don't understand why I need a getter and a setter named modelId and I don't have them cause I havn't any field named modelId. modelId can't match one of the three modelType: modelReport, modelProposal, modelInternship, for which I have getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

i guess `modelId` is the id of the nested entity and not the entity itself hence i would expect something like this

```
"SELECT f FROM Formation f WHERE f.model" + modelType + ".ModelId = :modelId")
```